# I Can Edit SD Card on Windows XP but Not on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, permissions, sdhc

I have an 8GB SDHC card which I have used to upload pictures onto my Windows XP machine using an SD card reader ("SanDisk Ultra II"). I could also delete pictures and create folders on the card. I recently obtained a new computer that runs Windows 7 and, while I can view and upload the photos, I am unable to delete photos or create folders. When I attempt to do either of these two operations, the desired option does not appear in the menu ("Delete"/"New Folder"). Also, the shortcut keys do not work (e.g. the Delete key and Alt+F+W+F).

I have attempted to change the Properties from Read-only, but am greeted with a "media is write protected".

I should add that when I insert the Card Reader back into my Windows XP computer, I am granted full write permissions.

Why can't I modify the SD Card from Windows 7? And, related, how can I fix this issue?

Let me know if you have any additional questions.

Comment: Its a laptop or desktop?

Comment: Both are laptops.

Comment: Have you tried using the card in another laptops which has windows 7?

Comment: Yes. Used in another laptop with Windows 7 and with the same results.

Comment: Is it formatted ntfs? if so that could cause problems, might need to add everyone with full permissions to the drive and the files if that is the case. Or pull the files off format it as fat32 then copy them back.

Comment: You may have a permissions issue in win 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would look at the security tab in the SD properties. I don't think the format (FAT vs NTFS) would drive the issue.

- Insert SD card, go to Computer
- Right click the SD card icon and click on Properties
- Click the security tab.
- Click edit under the Group or user names display.
- Click on Everyone (so that it is highlighted) then below in the permissions for Everyone area, tick Full Control.

---

I also found that the same options are available following the winding path of `Properties` > `Sharing` > `Advanced Sharing` > `Permissions`

Comment: I had been looking for the "Security Tab" earlier, but this is not present on whatever version of Windows 7 I have. I found that the same options are available following the winding path of `Properties > Sharing > Advanced Sharing > Permissions`. This seems to have done the trick, and so the above answer is essentially correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, 'til I 'named' the volume (SD card). Now I can delete folders and/or files.

Comment: This answer would be improved by explaining how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue on Lenovo G470, Windows 8.
I think problem is with windows default driver for card reader.

I solved problem by installing vendor specific driver (in my case realtek card reader driver).

You can download relevant driver from your laptop vendor site for your specific laptop model.